# Removing White Text with Black Borders From Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to remove text from images that has a black border with white fill. Take the image below as an example.

[image]

I have tried a few options utilizing opencv and skimage inpaint

```
import cv2
from skimage.restoration import inpaint
img = cv2.imread('Documents/test_image.png')
mask = cv2.threshold(img, 210, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1][:,:,0]
dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 7, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
image_result = inpaint.inpaint_biharmonic(img, mask,
                                          multichannel=True)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
cv2.imshow('image_result',image_result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems like the inpainting is just trying to fill with black as that is what it is identifying as being around the areas of interest. What I would like to do is remove the white text and black borders completely, or secondarily try to fill the white with more information from surrounding colors than just the black.

Comment: Find a mask for the black surrounding the text. The find a mask for the white text. Combine the masks.  But the OpenCV inpainting is generally of limited distance, best for thin scratches. It is not a patch matching inpainting method. Same in Skimage/Scipy.

Comment: Are there patch matching methods available in python to your knowledge?

Comment: No, not that I know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two inpainting methods in Python/OpenCV. Note that I use the saturation channel to create the threshold, since white and black have zero saturation, in principle.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread('white_black_text.png')

# convert to hsv and extract saturation
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
sat = hsv[:,:,1]

# threshold and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(sat, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply morphology dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# do inpainting
result1 = cv2.inpaint(img,thresh,11,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
result2 = cv2.inpaint(img,thresh,11,cv2.INPAINT_NS)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('white_black_text_threshold.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('white_black_text_inpainted1.png', result1)
cv2.imwrite('white_black_text_inpainted2.png', result1)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('result1',result1)
cv2.imshow('result2',result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold and morphology cleaned result:

[image]

Result 1 (Telea):

[image]

Result 2 (Navier Stokes):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best solution I could come up with, still open to others with more experience showing me a better way if anyone has an idea.

```
mask = cv2.threshold(img, 245, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1][:,:,0]
new_mask = cv2.dilate(mask, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10,10)))
dst = cv2.inpaint(img, new_mask, 7, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

[image]

Comment: You can try this code: 

import cv2  

file = "1J1Dz.png"  
img = cv2.imread(file)  
saturation=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]
value=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,2]
s_and_v=cv2.bitwise_and(saturation, value)
mask2 = cv2.threshold(s_and_v, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
new_mask2 = cv2.dilate(mask2, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7)))
dst2 = cv2.inpaint(img, new_mask2, 15, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imwrite('test.png', dst2)